# What happens to locked answer?

Tags: discussion

I have recently seen the [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/16346/5456) which is locked. What happen to that answer, does it get delete out? Or get opened after some editing by moderators?

Comment: The post you are referring to was unlocked and edited and is now fair game. Maybe we are lucky and jonsca will state something about the procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124749/make-locking-posts-more-granular) has a good explanation of what locking a post does:

> you cannot
>
> - Upvote or downvote on it
> - Edit it
> - Vote to close or reopen it
> - Comment on it
> - Add new answers to it

Unfortunately, as moderators we can't fine-tune which of these site functions gets "locked" and which don't.

In the case of that post, there was a brief editing dispute on an answer, and I locked the post to prevent further editing.  I won't go into the details because the issue was dealt with and the misunderstanding was cleared up.  I unlocked it shortly thereafter.  If anyone tried to add anything (comments, etc.), hopefully they were able to do so at that point.